# Matplotlib plt.figure() Raises TCLError on Ubuntu (X resources-dependent)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, x11

**Matplotlib Installation**

I've had a matplotlib install for quite some time, using the official repository, and had no issues until today. Using `plt.figure()` raises an error with the `TKAgg` backend, but any other backend works seamlessly (`Qt4Agg` and `Agg` were tested). Both my installs were using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib python3-matplotlib
```

I also have a few virtualenv installs of matplotlib (using no-globals), with matplotlib installed using Python2 or 3 in each environment.

**Code Snippet**

Here is the basic code snippet that is producing errors, in both my virtualenv installations and with the system installations:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.axvline(x=1)
plt.show()
```

**System Install Error**

Now, if I run the above code snippet on the system install (Python2 or 3), I get:

```
  plt.figure()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 435, in figure
  **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
  return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 109, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
  figManager = FigureManagerTkAgg(canvas, num, window)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 537, in __init__
  self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, self.window )
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 682, in __init__
  NavigationToolbar2.__init__(self, canvas)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2679, in __init__
  self._init_toolbar()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 736, in _init_toolbar
  command=getattr(self, callback))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 716, in _Button
  master=self, text=text, padx=2, pady=2, image=im, command=command)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2163, in __init__
  Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2093, in __init__
  (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "rgba:0000/0000/0000/dddd"
```

**VirtualEnv Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 7, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
ImportError: cannot import name _tkagg
```

**Other Information**

/etc/matplotlibrc

```
#### CONFIGURATION BEGINS HERE
backend      : TkAgg
```

> Ubuntu Version: 15.10
>
> System Python Version: 2.7.10 and 3.4.3+
>
> System Matplotlib Version: 1.4.2
>
> VirtualEnv Python Version: 2.7.9
>
> VirtualEnv Matplotlib Version: 1.4.3

~/Xresources

```
*foreground:     rgba:0000/0000/0000/dddd
*background:     rgb:10/10/10
```

**Stack Overflow Similar Questions**

I also looked at the following questions, but found nothing that solved my issue. I cannot simply delete my VM, since this is my personal computer I am using. Also, my issue I believe is independent of Anaconda (I have Anaconda installed, but am not using it, and all these Python executables are not from Anaconda installers).

[matplotlib backend_tkagg TclError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25321841/matplotlib-backend-tkagg-tclerror)
[matplotlib example code throws TclError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950789/matplotlib-example-code-throws-tclerror)
[TclError matplotlib 1.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145314/tclerror-matplotlib-1-5-0)

**Question**

Does anyone have any suggestions to fix the above error while keeping my X resource configurations? I have fixed previous errors in a program (Chimera) that uses Matplotlib, which raised a different TCLError by modifying my XResources configurations. Similarly, clearing my XResources configurations seems to fix the issue, however, as I have had the same `~/.Xresources` file for nearly a year now, I find it unlikely that this is the cause, and would also like to keep my color configurations.

Commenting out the two lines defined above, and then reloading my configurations using `xrdb ~/.Xresources` fixes the issue, but I would rather not have to redefine my X configurations.